# 'window is not defined' issue when I integrate polkadot{js} extension into my dapp

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, polkadot-js-extension

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I reload my browser, I get the error shown in the attached image.

However, once I disable bellow imports, the screen works fine.

And also error message say that bellow code is related.
`node_modules/@polkadot/extension-dapp/bundle.js:10:13`

`@polkadot/extension-dapp`

`@polkadot/identicon`

If anyone has a kind mind, please see repo.

https://github.com/Interoperable-swap/frontend/issues/2

[image]

*Using:Next.js

Comment: This issue is related to the use of NextJS, see this issue in the library GitHub: https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/issues/1050

Comment: @AlexBean
Thank you for your reply.
I have looked at the issue, but it seems that nothing has been resolved. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about how Next.js renders the frontend code. From their docs:

> Next.js is universal, which means it executes code first server-side,
> then client-side. The window object is only present client-side.

In order to get around that problem you will need to use a dynamic import as opposed to the normal import you currently have: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

In your code it will be something like this.
In `client/context/TransactionContext.js` change the import of the library from:

```
import { web3Accounts,web3Enable  } from '@polkadot/extension-dapp'
```

To:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const web3Accounts = dynamic(() => import('@polkadot/extension-dapp'), { ssr: false });
const web3Enable = dynamic(() => import('@polkadot/extension-dapp'), { ssr: false });
```

And in the file `client/components/Header.js` change the import:

```
import Identicon from '@polkadot/react-identicon'
```

To:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Identicon = dynamic(() => import('@polkadot/react-identicon'), { ssr: false });
```

Comment: Thanks your advice!
`TypeError: web3Enable is not a function`
new error was happened if I did as you mentioned but I finally did it because I wrote them in async function like bellow
const { web3Enable,web3Accounts, web3FromSource } = await import("@polkadot/extension-dapp");

Comment: Really? That code worked for me. But glad you finally fix it